# airbnb-prop-types - SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on `forbidExtraProps`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

```
import forbidExtraProps from 'prop-types-exact'; 
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I'm getting this error when using `airbnb-prop-types` and testing with Jest. I think is a problem with the configuration of Babel version 7.

Dependencies (from package.json):

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "@svgr/rollup": "^2.4.1",
    "airbnb-js-shims": "^2.1.1",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "babel-preset-airbnb": "^3.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
    "eslint": "^5.7.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^22.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.3",
    "gh-pages": "^1.2.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "jest-cli": "^24.1.0",
    "jest-environment-enzyme": "^7.0.1",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.6.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.7.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.1",
    "rollup": "^0.64.1",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^9.1.3",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^1.6.2",
    "rollup-plugin-url": "^1.4.0",
    "why-did-you-update": "^1.0.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "airbnb-prop-types": "^2.11.0",
    "ajv": "^6.0.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "focus-trap-react": "^6.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "object.assign": "^4.1.0",
    "object.values": "^1.0.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react-portal": "^4.2.0"
  }
```